# Expectation of a function of a Binomial random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is it possible to obtain the explicit form of the following expectation, $E\left[\left(\frac{X}{1+X}\right)^n\right]$, where $X$ is a random variable following Binomial distribution with parameters $m$(number of Bernoulli trials) and $p$(the probability of success in each trial) and $n$ is a positive integer greater than or equal to 2? Thank you in advance.

Comment: sympy cannot sum it symbolically, so maybe not? Why do you need it, you should explain your use case.